# .NET MPI implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, mpi

What is the most mature .NET MPI implementation? A quick google search turned up the two below, but I'm not familiar with either of them. I believe the first item (mpi.net) is based on [Microsoft MPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831(VS.85).aspx). Any thoughts?

http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/

http://www.purempi.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MPI.NET's FAQ](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/faq/?category=general)   says

> On Unix, however, MPI.NET adapts itself to the native MPI detected at configure time, and can work with (at least) Open MPI, LAM/MPI, and MPICH2.

although on Windows it appears to be a completely managed solution.  AFAICT, Pure Mpi.NET is only a managed solution.

I haven't used either of these implementations -- in fact, it's been a while since I've used *any* MPI -- but I would suspect that MPI.NET has a higher likelihood of overall stability since it will actually use the "tried-and-true" Unix implementations when available.  Those Unix implementations have been in the field for a much longer time, and as such are generally less likely to be buggy -- or at least if there are bugs, they are probably well-known by now.